# React useEffect and componentWillUnmount with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

There is a profile page. Here the `props.profile()` loads every time when I visit my profile. It updates the Redux store and basically adds the user to the state. There is a `logout` button as well. After logging out it redirects to the home page, the action and reducer clear the Redux state and deletes the token from the localStorage.

If I go to my profile page and log out **before the profile loads**, then even though I already clicked the `logout` button, the `props.profile()` still loads. Like [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8gy2.jpg).

I think there is something wrong with my `useEffect` because the component doesn't unmount when clicking the `logout` button.

```
useEffect(() => {
        props.profile();

        return;
    }, [props]);
```

There is a `return;` too but I'm not sure what to do with that.

**Desired outcome:** if I click logout, I want the component to unmount and just clear the state.

LOGOUT Action:

```
export const logout = () => (dispatch) => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    dispatch({
        type: LOGOUT,
    });
};
```

LOGOUT Reducer:

```
case LOGOUT:
            return {
                user: {},
                authenticated: false,
                loading: false,
                error: null,
                token: null,
            };
```

Comment: The `return` function of `useEffect` will be used for any cleanups - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Comment: As soon as you go to `profile page` it will call the `useEffect` and it's pretty fast operation and i don't think you can logout before its gets called.

Comment: I put the `logout` button on the profile page for testing purposes and I can quickly click it before the `props.profile()` runs. Then it logs me out but the `props.profile()` still runs after.

Answer (score 1):

Your component always unmounts, regardless of `return` in your `useEffect`. What is not happening is *something being called on unmount*.

Try chaning your code to something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        props.profile();

        return () => props.logout(); //logout should be your redux action
    }, [props.profile, props.logout]); // Reduce triggers of this method by not leaving `props` here
```

Comment: The problem still persists. I go to my profile page, it loads my profile page, but if I click on the `logout` button before it loads the `props.profile()`, then even after logging out, it will load the profile and put data in the Redux store.

Comment: @David I've added some changes to the code, could you try again?

Comment: @David if your page is mounted via a navigation library theres a good chance the page isn't actually getting unmounted when you swap pages.

Comment: Yes, I navigate with react-router-dom and <NavLink>. So with that updated code: I'm on /profile but if I go to /feed then it logs me out automatically. So how should I unmount it then?

Comment: It's because you have this `[props.profile, props.logout]`. Even for change in profile (prop.profile) it might trigger logout.